# can not change Cardstream gateway redirect url

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I'm testing cardstream payment gateway with sandbox details. I tried to change redirectURL. when I change it I got below error. if I keep it with "https://www.merchant.com/payment/" , it is working.

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://gateway.cardstream.com/sdk/web/v1/js/hostedforms.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="payment-form" method="post" action="https://gateway.cardstream.com/hosted/" data-hostedform-modal>
    <input type="hidden" name="merchantID" value="100001" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="SALE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currencyCode" value="826" />
    <input type="hidden" name="countryCode" value="826" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1001" />
    <input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="Test purchase" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirectURL" value="https://www.merchant.com/payment/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="07599ef4cdb2e26cb2bf34a9c65190a7ce82494bc1df144c3bb0d20ee2655d8278dc663b2b0421ef12b8f081e821151bb4c644277c5d65b5523a96539b53b5aa" />
    <input type="submit" value="Pay Now">
</form>
<script>
var form = new window.hostedForms.classes.Form(document.forms[0]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got it from cardstream official docs

Comment: I tested your form and it works (even tested next step with a test card), the error code your getting 66343 means: Invalid signature field, but its fine, presuming your not changing any values.

Comment: form is works. I want to change the redirectURL. if you change to something else, it won't work.

Comment: yes, because then the signature is different, how it works is all fields get URL encoded then signed into a sha512 signature with your signing key, see their repo for examples like https://github.com/cardstream/SDK-PHP - can test sigs by posting to this page https://gateway.cardstream.com/devtools/sigtest.php